# styling a select when selected?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a style for the html `select` box when it's just sitting there, and then a different color when the user has clicked on it and the items are listed?

I want something like this:

```
select {
    background:#fff;
    color:#929496;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Then the colors are inverted, so the text is white and the background is grey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:focus` pseudo-class:

```
select:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #929496;
}
```

This also applies the inverted colors to its options when they appear.

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vukM9)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT boxes are OS-level controls, not HTML controls. You cannot reliably style them across browsers. You can replace them with various HTML+CSS-based techniques.

Comment: Just a thought, but to *replace* a `select` element, and retain its function, probably requires JavaScript as well as html and css.

Comment: Browser support for changing the text and background colors of `select`s and `option`s is quite agreeable across vendors though, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
    ::-moz-selection {
    color:white;
    background:#3A75AF ;
    }

    ::selection {
    color:white;
    background:#3A75AF ;
    }

    </style>
```

Will do your job :) Works everywhere. Please dont ask about IE.